# How to add a class alias in Laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel, namespaces, laravel-4

I added this [MailChimp API](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/) to Laravel 4 with Composer and I am able to use this API like so:

```
$MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp();
```

How can I create an instance of `MailChimp()` without the path like this:

```
$MailChimp = new MailChimp();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually add an alias to `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => array(
    //other laravel alias

    'MailChimp' => 'Drewm\MailChimp'
 );
```

Now you can use `MailChimp` anywhere in laravel app.

Answer (score 2):

You can "use" it on the top of your php source file.

```
use Drewm\MailChimp;

$MailChimp = new MailChimp();
```

Comment: This works and is a great PHP solution. However, for Laravel projects, I prefer the solution from egig.